# P2P Connection with gRPC

Tags: c#, asp.net, chat, grpc, p2p

I'm currently working on a P2P Service with the gRPC Service in C# ASP.NET.
I know how the whole process works but is there a way to enable server and client for one so that he can receive and also post messages?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC has concepts of client and server.

Only clients originate connections to to servers and only clients can initiate RPC calls against servers but, once a client has established a connection to a server, the client can send a single or stream of messages and the server can respond with a single or stream of messages.

If you want true peer-to-peer in which any peer can originate and respond to RPCs from any other peer, then you need to implement both a client **and** a server in the peer.

Think of "client" and "server" more like gRPC roles.